# Truth assertions library comparing to AssertJ

Tags: assertj, google-truth, fest-assert

I used `FEST-Assert` and moved to `AssertJ` after it stopped development.

Recently I was pointed to **Google** repository with another assertions library `Truth` (http://google.github.io/truth/).

Reading the examples I can not find any advantage of start using it over `AssertJ`. So it is just matter of taste what to use. But maybe I missed the point, did I?

Comment: https://truth.dev/comparison.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From one of their [comments](https://github.com/google/truth/issues/43#issuecomment-71222029) at GitHub:

> The core difference is that the design of Truth includes two specific
>   areas of extensibility - that of a strategy for proposition failure -
>   such that a "subject" for Integers, or a subject for Strings can be
>   re-used in the context of completely different results for failure.  A
>   notable example is the distinction between JUnit's use of
>   AssertionError and it's AssumptionViolationException.  Truth lets you
>   use the same proposition classes for both.
>
> The other area of flexibility is the ability to create new
>   assertion/proposition types and hook them in without declaring
>   possibly conflicting static methods to import.  This can be for new
>   types (say, adding protobufs) or for new uses of existing types (say,
>   Strings that are treated as Uris).  This is the assertAbout() feature.
>
> Other than that, Truth is very similar to AssertJ, since it was
>   inspired by FEST, of which AssertJ is a fork of the 2.0 development
>   line.

To sum up, Truth is designed to be a bit more extensible and flexible, but AssertJ will be great (possibly the greatest) for assertions on standard types.

Comment: Thanks, Michal, I think it is matter to try and find out